# Removing Duplicates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my second attempt at this.  I am trying to update data in a SQL table where there are duplicates to resolve the duplicate.

Data Structure

```
DocNumbr     SeQnumbr     Dex_Row_Id
CRM025222    32768            1
CRM025222    32768            2
CRM025222    16384            3
```

Desired Result

```
DocNumbr     SeQnumbr     Dex_Row_Id
CRM025222    49152            1
CRM025222    32768            2
CRM025222    16384            3
```

For each duplicate, I need to update the seqnumbr to be the max value of seqnumbr for the duplicates by Docnumbr + 16384.  Dex_row_ID is a primary key and is unique.

My Attempt

```
Begin
Declare @count as integer = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS DUPLICATES
FROM            dbo.RM10101
GROUP BY DocNumbr, SeqNumbr
HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1))

Declare @counter as integer =1
While @Counter < @count


begin



Update RM10101 set SeqNumbr= (select MAX(dex_row_id) FROM RM10101 E2
WHERE E2.DocNumbr = RM10101.DocNumbr AND E2.SeqNumbr = RM10101.SeqNumbr) + (16384+) 
WHERE dex_row_id < (select MAX(dex_row_id) FROM RM10101 E2
WHERE E2.DocNumbr = RM10101.DocNumbr AND E2.SeqNumbr = RM10101.SeqNumbr
) 
SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
end
```

I have tried the code above, but the value being used to add to 16384 is the max seqnumbr of all rows, I need it be the max for the set of duplicates.  I am not a dba, but am being pressed into duty on this and am really lost on how to get the join or subquery right.  This is being done in SQL Server 2008.  Originally I was told it was 2000, so if there is a better way using a cte or some other new method, I would be open to it.  Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Build Test Data
create table #test_table(
    DocNumber varchar(255),
    SeqNumber int,
    Dex_Row_Id int
)

insert into #test_table
select 'CRM025222', 32768, 1 union all
select 'CRM025222', 32768, 2 union all
select 'CRM025222', 16384, 3

-- Solution: Start
;with cte as(
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by DocNumber order by SeqNumber desc)
    from #test_table
)
update cte 
    set SeqNumber = SeqNumber + 16384
where 
    rn = 1     
-- Solution: End

select * from #test_table

-- Drop test data
drop table #test_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not sure how to sure this.  how would I get all the rows into the #test_table.  The data that I gave is just a sample, there many different values.

Comment: That was just a test data. Replace #test_table with your real table. I put comments on the code to show which part is the solution.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I think this is close.  It seems like your solution is updating a non-duplicate row.  If my data looks like:

    Docnumbr     SeqNumbr     Dex_Row_ID
    doc1          147457       12
    doc2          147457       13
    doc1          147457       14

The result is
    Docnumbr     SeqNumbr     Dex_Row_ID
    doc1          163841       12
    doc2          163841       13
    doc1          147457       14

Thanks!